# Is it possible to electroplate iron onto nickel in a sodium chloride solution?

Tags: electrochemistry, everyday-chemistry, electroplating

Over the years I have salvaged many laptop and power tool batteries and collected a lot of metal strips, but I don't know if they are made of nickel or nickel-plated steel.
I have a piece that I know for sure is pure nickel, and I would like to electrically deposit onto it all the nickel from the salvaged strips using a solution of table salt and thus, effectively, separate the nickel from the iron.

However, I don't know how to make sure that I actually electroplated nickel and not some alloy of nickel and iron or just iron. For this reason, I'm wondering if it is possible to deposit iron onto nickel in a table salt solution. I've tried searching on the Internet, but I've only found information about electroplating nickel onto iron, not the other way around.

Comment: If there is both nickel and iron in solution, nickel will deposit with priority. But using high enough voltage= low enough cathode potential, iron may co-deposit.

Comment: @Poutnik Do you know how low I should keep the voltage in order to deposit almost pure nickel?